# Extjs checkbox column: make difference between click on checkbox and the rest of the field

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

i have a grid with a checkboxcolumn, all works fine but i would like to take different action between clicking on the checkbox itself and clicking besides it in the same field.
 Is this feasable in ExtJs ? I work with version 3.3.1 but i guesss that an example from another version would get me started.

```
var checkColumn = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
    header: 'Checklist OK ?',
    dataIndex: 'checklist_ok',
    width: 20,
    align: 'center'
});

cmDiverse = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults: {
        "sortable": true,
        "menuDisabled": false,
        "align": "right"
    },
    store: storeDiverse,
    columns: [{
        "id": "id",
        "header": "id",
        "hidden": true,
        "dataIndex": "id",
        "width": 20
    },
```

checkColumn, ...

```
gridDiverse = new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.EditorGridPanel({
    id: "gridDiverse",
    enableDragDrop: false,
    loadMask: true,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    layout: 'anchor',
    cm: cmDiverse,
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot differentiate between click inside and outside the checkbox, because all the listeners are on the column, and the checkbox is just a formatting of the text inside the column, not a real element.